# What do we do with this question that is really an answer?

Tags: discussion

There is this question that is really an answer: [Ubuntu Solution for the NVIDIA display issue on Brightness control and Video PlayBack](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031541/307523)

There are two answers posted below it that are probably questions or comments.

What to do???

Answer (score 6):

I think Zanna once again gets to the point with her comment:

> Please could you reformat your post so that the question is a question and the answer is posted as an answer below?

Provided you understand it, you should go for it and split the post yourself. I’d make the answer community wiki, just to be fair.

The existing “answers” should get downvotes, flags or close votes as needed. It’s relevant that both answers got posted by the same user.

> The installation process went fine (…) and the result was the same.

is merely a “me too” comment, I flagged as NAA and didn’t vote.

> I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 …

is a “me too” comment with a hidden “I tried several solutions” question embedded. I flagged as NAA, left the usual “If you have another question” comment and didn’t vote.

Comment: I woke up this morning and the two answers have been deleted by Zanna and others.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that reformatting as suggested by [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031541/ubuntu-solution-for-the-nvidia-display-issue-on-brightness-control-and-video-pla#comment1705643_1031541) and [dessert](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17984/250300) should be preferred. However, OP (or the community) may fail to do that, so the current situation would persist.

After a reasonable amount of time, I would proceed to vote to close the question as “unclear what you’re asking” since OP did not present any meaningful question.

Moreover, there is a request in the “question”:

> If any other alternate was found kindly post it below.

This would break the site principles:

- An answer posted by OP (even if accepted) would flow among other answers based on votes while an answer in the question is kept on top.
- OP loses reputation given for their solution – gets just 5 for a question upvote compared to 10 for an answer upvote.
- As [dessert mentioned](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17983/what-do-do-with-this-question-that-is-really-an-answer#comment37866_17985) (before this edit), regular SE users usually look for the solution in the answers section. The solution inside a question looks then like an unsolved problem.

Closing the question would avoid at least some of these problems.

Comment: Additionally, I often find me not reading the question to the end, but scrolling down to the answers and see whether there’s something helpful. A format like this breaks my workflow! ;)